# Tags page 1: 2 missing wikis: [guitar-effects] and [amplifiers]

Tags: discussion

This is more or less just an announcement that these 2 tag wikis come up bare on page 1 of [music.stackexchange.com/tags](https://music.stackexchange.com/tags): [guitar-effects](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guitar-effects) and [amplifiers](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amplifiers).

I don't feel qualified in these areas to write these wikis myself. If I understand things correctly, it's important (particularly with the potential for shopping questions on these two) to describe how these tags should be used, not just a definition (which I probably could manage). But doesn't this site, to some extent, still represent a merger with Guitars.SE? So there's some fuzzy territory for me here. There's some special privileges for guitar gear that other instruments may or may not enjoy. Or maybe there isn't and I'm imagining things.

Thoughts?

Comment: The Guitars merge brought over questions, that's all.